# Can the read api receive events that the write api does not receive or raise?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs

Say I have a read API and a write API:

```
MyApp.Write.api
MyApp.Read.api
```

Both API's handle integration events from other apis/microservices.  Say I had certain integration events that only need to be handled by the read api.  Then is it necessary for the write api to handle them first? The reason I ask is because the write api contains an integration log and I am wandering if it is necessary to log all events that reach the read.api in this integration log i.e. not just the events that originate from the write api.

I am effectively asking if the write.api should generate all events for the read api or whether it is acceptable for the read api to receive events that the write api does not receive?

Please note that both solutions will work from my perspective.  I am asking from the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: The log is an orthogonal concern to the architecture. You could not count logging as "command". In other words, you could make your Read API to write its logs without breaking the responsibility segregation of CQRS.

Comment: @Laiv, thanks.  Are you saying it is acceptable for the read api to handle events that are not handled by the write api?

Comment: That would be convenient. For the sake of the concern segregation. Consider both APIs to be different channels of communication. Agnostic each other

Answer (score 1):

I think it can. Some integration events are just for the consistency of duplicated data in microservices and there is no need for business logic.

I did not understand that the events are published via a message broker (async method) or RPC (sync method) is used.

If you used RPC, I think the best practice here is to have an API Gateway to dispatch events (with RPC call probably) to write and read API after it logs the event.

If you used message brokers, to have a log of events, you can use message re-routing such that all events must go to the Inbox of your microservice, and the handler (after logging the event) publishes an event for the read and the write model.